# AutoMapper not mapping child list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a parent object(brand) with list of 5 child object(campaign):

```
Brand response = await _brandRepository.GetAsync(request.Id);

//other properties mapped fine, but Campaing is null.. 
var result = _mapper.Map<BrandDto>(response);
return result;
```

I have these definations for mapping:

```
CreateMap<Domain.Entity.Campaign, CampaignDto>();
CreateMap<Domain.Entity.Brand, BrandDto>();
```

objects:

```
public class BrandDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CampaignDto> Campaing { get; set; }
}
public class CampaignDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCampaignId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public CampaignDto ParentCampaign { get; set; }
    public BrandDto Brand { get; set; }
}
```

entities:

```
public class Brand : SqlEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Campaign> Campaign { get; set; } = new List<Campaign>();
}
public class Campaign : SqlEntityBase
{
    public int? ParentCampaignId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Guid ImpressionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntryStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Campaign ParentCampaign { get; set; }
}
```

If I map child object manually it works fine, but its not cool
how can I make this proper way?

Comment: Can you provide the Entity classes, please?

Comment: @MatterOfFact did it

Comment: There is a typo in the BrandDto class: Campaing instead of Campaign

Comment: AutoMapper will only map without further configuring if the source and destination property name are equal.